# Getting error when trying to insert a record that has composite primary keys

Tags: php, sql, laravel, models

I have a **Many-to-Many relation**, so the implementation require to create new table with two primary keys ,,

here's the new table :

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('friendship', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user1_id')->index('fk_user_has_user_user1_idx');
        $table->integer('user2_id')->index('fk_user_has_user_user2_idx');
        $table->boolean('state')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->primary(['user1_id','user2_id']);
    });
}
```

but when try to insert data using this function :
     //Insert new FriendShip into DataBase

```
public function InsertFriendShip($User1Id, $User2Id, $State)
{
    $friend = new FriendShip();

    $friend->User1_Id = $User1Id;
    $friend->User2_Id = $User2Id;
    $friend->State = $State;

    // save new FriendShip to the database
   if(!$friend->save())
       return 'created';
}
```

ok it create the new record in database but although it return this **Error** 
**PDO::lastInsertId() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

Comment: You mean create a new table with a composite primary key (comprised of 2 fields)

Comment: yes that what I mean

Comment: first of all, from the error you are getting, it does not seem to be an issue with inserting an existing primary key, rather a type incompatibility/inconsistency issue. You need to make sure what you are passing as "User1Id" is a string (I am not familiar with PHP, do not know what "array given" means)

Comment: "User1Id" is an integer as you see >> $table->integer('user1_id')->index('fk_user_has_user_user1_idx');

and i'm sure that i pass at as integer too

Comment: I do not know which function is lastInsertId(), but again, it is expecting a string parameter, and getting something else instead. That's all I can say from here.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to pass parameters as string and see ..

Comment: Eloquent doesn't support composite primary keys. If it's a pivot table, you may work using methods on [ManyToMany](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) such as `attach()` , `detach()`,  `sync()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can deduce, you have a `Friendship` Eloquent Model attached to the `friendship` pivot table. The problem with that is that Eloquent doesn't work with composite primary keys, so there's no real way of doing that.

You should have a look at the [Laravel Eloquent Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many) to see how to implement many-to-many relationships. In you case you could have a `User` model that looks something like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'friendship', 'user1_id', 'user2_id');
    }

    public function addFriend(User $user)
    {
        $this->friends()->attach($user->id);
    }

    public function removeFriend(User $user)
    {
        $this->friends()->detach($user->id);
    }

}
```

You can then add or remove a friend for any user very easily:

```
$user1 = User::find($id1);
$user2 = User::find($id2);

$user1->addFriend($user2);
//or
$user1->removeFriend($user2);
```

Comment: it works well for removeFriend ,, but addFriend it get this error >> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`viswalldb`.`friendship`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_user_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user1_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `friendship` () values ())

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. The lastInsertId call is done for autoincrementing tables. They by definition have only simple primary_keys.

If you add in your model

```
protected $primaryKey = ['FIELD1', 'FIELD2'];
public $incrementing = false;
```

Then it should work, it did for me. Now it won't call lastInsertId